# AngularJS Slideshow $scope.timeout(); not canceling the timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, slideshow

When SetState() is being called it should reset the timer. I've only written the cancel part but it does not seem to cancel the timeout. I also do not get any information from the console. So I'm stuck.

```
$scope.customTimeout = null;
$scope.SlideTimer = function() {
    $timeout.cancel($scope.customTimeout);
    $scope.customTimeout = $timeout(function() {
        if ($scope.slideState == (slideAmount -1))
            $scope.slideState = 0;
        else
            $scope.slideState++;
    }, 2000).then(function() {
        $scope.SlideTimer();
    });
};

$scope.SlideTimer();

$scope.SetState = function(State) {
    $scope.slideState = State;
    $timeout.cancel($scope.customTimeout);
    console.log("set state to " + State);
};
```

This is just a part of my whole code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, is `$scope.SetState` even called?

Comment: Yes, it is called with a ng-click. I also put a console.log in the function and that logs. SetState does work. It just does not cancel the $timeout for some reason.